# .NET 4.5, EF 5 and MembershipProvider

Tags: membership-provider, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

Does anyone know if there is going to be created a default MembershipProvider to use with EF 5 (like SqlMembershipProvider and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider) or we will still have to create custom ones (that is for Code First of course)?

Comment: You should not combine membership provider and EF at all. Membership provider has its own logic encapsulated in stored procedures - simply use it as is or you can break its secure implementation! Use EF for classes you own not for system classes.

Comment: As far as I know and MSDN tells me the MembershipProvider is an abstract class which can be inherited in order to implement a custom membership provider. Additionally in MSDN is stated that you will want to implement your own provider if you are using Oracle for example. Perhaps you are referring to SqlMembershipProvider, which is a concrete implementation, comes with its own database (aspnetdb) and uses stored procedures.

Comment: Also I know that when you need to store user credentials it will be best if you implement your own provider, inheriting from the MembershipProvider and not just randomly inventing your own logic.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to SqlMembrrshipProvider. If you want to store your own implementation of user credentials you will need to invent your own logic because MembershipProvider API is dependent on fixed classes like MembershipUser which cannot be mapped by EF code first.

Comment: However I was not referring to SqlMembershipProvider, but to the abstract class MembershipProvider. So the stored procedures are not a problem. Also mapping to MembershipUser might be difficult, but is not impossible - I think somewhere here I found a solution using the adapter pattern. However this was not my initial question. I just wanted to know if there is going to be created a default MembershipProvider for EF in .NET 4.5, just like the SQL one - something like EfMembershipProvider. Other than that I am aware of many of the current problems when trying to use MembershipProvider with EF.

Comment: So the answer to your question is: No it will not.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that coming, but I really hoped they would do something, especially after the numerous projects in CodePlex, CodeProject and other places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually after the long comments and explanations it results that there will be a default MembershipProvider for EF and - guess what, guess what - it is called EFMembershipProvider. [Here is a link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.efproviders.efmembershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)Now this is really cool because third party implementations of MembershipProvider will no longer be needed (or the respective manual implementation - it was kind of BIG and total overkill for small projects).

**UPDATE**
Currently it seems that this provider is not available. I do not know if it will be developed and included in the future either.

Since we are encouraged to use SimpleMembershipProvider and migrations when using EF Code First that is what I am doing now. You can also implement the ExtendedMembershipProvider, which requires a little bit more effort.

For me the best solution for now is to inherit SimpleMembershipProvider and modify only the things that I need (I am using most of the code from my previous implementation of MembershipProvider), for example logging with email or username.

Comment: I guess it will still need some work to use it with different database. I don't think it will use code first beacause code first is not part of .NET but this class looks like part of .NET. So every othe database server will require replacing EDMX with your own.

Comment: Well this scenario is defenitely possible, especially after they separated EF from .NET. However that shows that they are working real hard on EF and its integration with the framework - maybe in the future we will see such advanced feture as well.

Comment: I am currently trying to create a very simple project using the ef providers and code first, I will see what will come out probably in Monday (as Saturday and Sunday are time to rest for me).

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a CodeFirst MembershipProvider & Role with my Silversite CMS ASP.NET library, that can be found at silversite.codeplex.com. The library also supports multiple DbContexts for CodeFirst databases.
As far as I know though currently the implementation is broken, and I didn't have the time to fix it yet. Also Profile and Session providers still are lacking. But I've got the code from the MySql providers that should not be too hard to port.